# Vertical lines seen on review badge progress pop-up

Tags: bug, design, review-badges

Site: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage

On review pages, when I click on badge progress, I see vertical white lines that are out of place in the pop-up that then appears. Seems to be a CSS issue.

[image]

Comment: Related? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369888/4751173

Comment: Just zoom to 100%

Answer (score 3):

I'm just saying this unsightly bug hasn't gone away, so I'm posting an answer. It's one way to bump the OP's post…

I would describe it as: thin white *and blue*  lines bleeding into the “Badge report”

> [image]

When I click on the progress bar on the *review* page,  white *horizontal* lines appear

> [image]

And if I click on the review tab, you can see the same thin blue lines bleeding into the report

> [image]

Comment: Well it's only on seen on Chrome isn't it? So why not try creating a minimal testcase and reporting it to Chrome's bugtracker?

Comment: @RobertLongson I have no idea if this is seen only on Chrome. And I have no idea what a minimal testcase means, or how to report to Chrome's bugtracker. I am not a developer or engineer. I'm just your ordinary Jane Doe.

Comment: @RobertLongson  but maybe you should post the comment as an answer?

Comment: My comment does not answer the question, nor does yours really as you're just restating the question in order to bump it. I imagine it will attract downvotes over time because of that. There's Glorfindel's comment that points to Chrome only.

Comment: Well, rather than post a duplicate post I "bumped" the OP's question.

Comment: That's what improvement edits and bounties are for.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm not going to put a bounty on that! It's not that important. And I thought about editing, but I didn't know or see what I could "fix" or improve.

Comment: You could have edited the question to add the extra information that you instead put in your answer?

Comment: @MartijnPieters wouldn't the terms used in my answer also appear in the search box?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I was specifically looking for *questions* tagged `bug` and had trouble finding this post. I had forgotten how old it was, I only found it because I found the related post over on MSO, which linked here. The fact that it didn't mention 'review' didn't help.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Gottcha! Didn't think of that. Force of habit I suppose, I very rarely use tags on EL&U to search for anything as many people misuse them.